# Does Slackbot Custom response have multiline support?

Tags: slack, slackbot

Slack offers this great functionality that a Slackbot can react to some specific words or expressions on public channels or DM to oneself.

Yet, you cannot input text that is multiline like we would do with `\n`.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this has been added.

Setting the response to `f\nu\nn` would result in:

[image: vertical fun]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a scoped feature but not released yet as described in this thread:

https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/988201735519965185?lang=en

[image: SlackHQ on Twitter]